# Windows Deployment Services cannot add localhost

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wds

I have two servers running Windows Deployment Services (WDS) Servers running. This past week they both 'lost' themselves as WDS servers. What I mean by that is under the Servers group in the WDS role there are no machines listed. When I try to add localhost I get "Access is denied." After enabling tracing, I got a log with the error below.

```
[3812] 09:40:49: Started the asyncCreateServer in the background thread.
[3992] 09:40:49: -> CDataServer::CreateServer
[3992] 09:40:49: -> CDataCache::GetWdsServer
[3992] 09:40:49: Failed to get the WDS Server
[3992] 09:40:49: <- CDataCache::GetWdsServer=80070005
[3992] 09:40:49: Failed to create IWdsServer object
[3992] 09:40:49: Done Getting the Status of the Server.
[3992] 09:40:49: <- CDataServer::CreateServer=80070005
[3812] 09:40:49: There was some error during the Creating the Server 0x80070005
```

I'm at a loss for what caused this and how to bring the servers back up. What causes this error?

Edit: It turns out there was a DNS issue with the DCs. There weren't syncing correctly and causing authentication errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check your services.  Specifically the `Windows Deployment Services Server` service.  If it's not running try and restart it.  I have seen issues where if WDS is running on a domain controller it will have problems starting on reboot.  Generally if I start it manually after the machine is stable it will fix the problem.  I'm not sure what the default start type is, but mine is "Automatic Delayed Start".